BarbaJS causing issues with radio/checkbox inputs
I am using Barba for page transitions but it is causing issues on forms which contain radio or checkbox inputs. For some reason it prevents those inputs from being checked. If I remove data-barba="container" then the inputs work again.
I looked over the docs but didn't see anything that seemed to explain this issue. The closest thing I found was the prevent strategy, but it doesn't seem applicable.


barba.init({
    timeout: 5000,
    debug: false,
    views: [{
        namespace: 'home',
        beforeEnter(data) {},
        afterEnter(data) {
            console.log('ran home page');
        },
        beforeLeave(data) { }
    }]
});
<body data-barba="wrapper">

  <main data-barba="container" data-barba-namespace="home">
    <form>
      <input type="radio" name="lorem" id="choice_1">
      <label for="choice_1" id="label_1">Lorem</label>
      <input type="radio" name="lorem" id="choice_2">
      <label for="choice_2" id="label_2">Lorem</label>
      <input type="radio" name="lorem" id="choice_3">
      <label for="choice_3" id="label_3">Lorem</label>
    </form>
  </main>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@barba/core"></script>
</body>




This appears to be an issue with more recent versions of Barba. I downgraded to 2.9.7 and the issue is no longer present
